# Google Spreadsheet: SUMIFS for same Column

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a problem in Google Spreadsheets:

I don't know why, but for Google there is a problem to use the `SUMIFS` formula.

When I try to use the `SUMIFS` formula for different criteria, for the **same** column, the output is always zero `0`.

I tried aleady other things, but anyways it doesn't work.
Here are my examples:

- Example 1

  ```
  =SUMMIFS('Sheet1'!G1:G100;'Sheet1'!C1:C100;"Criteria1";'Sheet1!C1:C100;"Criteria2";'Sheet1'!D1:D100;"Criteria3")
  ```
- Example 2

  ```
  =SUMMIFS('Sheet1'!G1:G100;'Sheet1'!C1:C100;{"Criteria1" ;"Criteria2"};'Sheet1'!D1:D100;"Criteria3")
  ```
- Example 3

  ```
  =SUMMIFS('Sheet1'!G1:G100;'Sheet1'!C1:C100;"*Criteria1"&"Criteria2";Sheet1'!D1:D100;"Criteria3")
  ```

Non of these work. I dont know what I should do. Anyone has an idea?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is probably correct. `SUMIF` criteria are connected AND not OR. This means **all** criteria need to be true.

So if you have two criteria on the same column it is very likely that only one of them can be true at the same time. Eg. column C can not be "Car" and "Book" at the same time. Therefore it is never count into the sum and always results `0`.

To OR connect criteria have a look here: [SUMIFS with OR](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/gggatjfMTcw).

Answer (score 1):

this formula works:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF('Sheet1'!G1:G100;'Sheet1'!C1:C100 & 'Sheet1'!C1:C100 ;{"Criteria1";"Criteria2"} ; 'Sheet1'!D1:D100;"Criteria3")))
```

Anyways the bad thing is, that this formula cant disting date criterias.

### Example1:

```
=SUMIFS(G2:G100;D2:D100;">=01.06.2011";F2:F100;"<=30.07.2011")
```

Does work, but this example 2 doesnt work:

### Example 2:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(D2:D100 & F2:F100;">=01.06.2011"&"<=30.07.2011";G2:G100)))
```

I Dont know why it doesnt work, has anybody a solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.